# Bloomberg function with ISIN nad return price

Tags: formula, price, bloomberg

I have a large base of ISIN of stocks and I would like to receive the last price and bid price. I use the following formulas

```
=BDH(A1&"@BGN equity";"PX_LAST";"20190729";"20190729";"days=A";"fill=p") 
=BDH(A1&"@BGN equity";"PX_BID";"20190729";"20190729";"days=A";"fill=p")
```

`A1` being the ISINs, but in response I get this **-#N/A Invadid Security**. How can I get the price?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bloomberg BHD function with ISIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080470/bloomberg-bhd-function-with-isin)

Comment: If that doesn't solve your issue, can you give a few examples of ISINs that don't work?